# Template deduction guide for function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I am trying to write some templated functions that accept either a `std::basic_string` or a char array from which the `basic_string` could be constructed.

My current solution is:

```
#include <string>

template<typename CharT>
void foo(std::basic_string<CharT> str)
{
    (void)str; // do something with str
}
template<typename CharT>
void foo(CharT const * arr)
{
    return foo(std::basic_string<CharT>{arr});
}

int main(void)
{
    foo("hello");
    foo(std::string{ "hello" });
    foo(L"hello");
    foo(std::wstring{ L"hello" });
}
```

But this means that for each function I have to write another function that calls the first one.  That's pretty annoying; is there an easier way to do it? Maybe it could be a template deduction guide, but as far as I know it does not exist for functions, only classes.

The first templated function is not sufficient because the template deduction fails: the compiler cannot deduce `CharT` in `std::basic_string<CharT>` from `CharT const *`. That is why I need a simpler way to tell this to the compiler.

Comment: Replace both overloads with a single one, `template<typename CharT>
void foo(std::basic_string_view<CharT> str)`?

Comment: @ildjarn Same problem, the template deduction fails.

Comment: when the `CharT const *` version is called, I just want to build a basic_string and call the first version like in the example. When this is not a templated function all is implicite, but here the compiled does not buid a `basic_string <char>` from a `char const *` because the deduction fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a bit more of research, the best option imo is to use the C++17 feature `std::basic_string_view`:

```
template<typename CharT>
void foo(std::basic_string_view<CharT> str)
{
    (void)str; // do something with str ...
               // while remembering that string_view does not own the string
}
```

So forget about the older explanation below if you have access to a C++17-compiler.

---

---

There are two cases here to consider. The **first case** is that you do not really want to do something special with the basic string, but rather you apply only methods also available for the `char`-array (and just want to make sure it's called correctly regardless of the parameters). In this case, I'd simply use a general template parameter:

```
template<typename string_type
        /* possibly some SFINAE to allow/disallow certain types */>
auto foo(string_type s)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

**Second case** is that you really want to do some special operation on the string which is not present for the char array. In this case you need an overload for `basic_string`, but you probably want to write it only once and not for each and every function you use. This is what the following `string_invoker` class tries to do (but it still needs some improvement, just working on it):

```
template<typename method>
struct string_invoker_impl
{
    string_invoker_impl(method m) : m(m) {}

    template<typename CharT>
    auto operator()(std::basic_string<CharT> str) const
    {
        return m(str);
    }

    template<typename CharT>
    auto operator()(CharT const * arr) const
    {
        return operator()(std::basic_string<CharT>{arr});
    }

    //possibly further methods for non-const array's, modification, etc.    

    method m;
};

auto string_invoker = [](auto m) { return string_invoker_impl<decltype(m)>{m}; };

auto foo_impl = [](auto str) {std::cout<< str <<std::endl; };
auto foo = string_invoker(foo_impl);

//you  can merge the previous two calls also in a single one:
//auto foo = string_invoker( [](auto str) {std::cout<< str <<std::endl; });


int main(void)
{
    foo("hello");
    foo(std::string{ "hello" });
    //foo(L"hello");                      //need std::wcout, thus it fails with std::cout
                                          //but it's no general problem, just overload your foo_impl function
    //foo(std::wstring{ L"hello" });
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de6cef99b72c0c76)

Comment: A possible improvment would be to restrict the pointer overload to char types (maybe through SFINAE using `std::char_traits`?)

Comment: @Rerito: could be, but I would think the construction of `std::basic_string` fails then anyways.

Comment: Oh yes, indeed since it uses `std::char_traits<CharT>` my bad

Comment: @Boiethios: please consider the update to my answer.

Comment: The update to your answer doesn't work. Specifically, it doesn't compile if you call `foo` with a `const char*`, which is the whole goal that the asker is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CodyGray: I left out the `#include` statements in the codebox, but those are spelled out in the demo. Otherwise -- you sure? Please see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7049f1f96e3949a), particularly for the `const char*` part. Was that your point?

Comment: @davidhigh It's true, the first function in the answer (i.e. the last update) doesn't compile when called with a string literal.

Answer (score 11):

Just bite the bullet and use 2 overloads. Any clever solution (which as [davidhigh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42781896/2805305) showed do exist) will only add unnecessary complexity, potential for bugs and confusion to the next reader.

You only write once but read multiple times. The small incovenient of writing a 1 line of body overload is worth doing against an non-idiomatic convoluted *smart way*.

Don't get me wrong, I love to find these *smart solutions* in C++, but if I found this solution in a production code it would take me a few good minutes just to figure out what the heck it is and what does it do, only to find out it just does what should have been a very basic thing in a complex way, I would ... well let's just say I wouldn't say nice things about the author of the code. Being lazy when writing code will cost you times over when you maintain, debug, extend, or even use the code.

**Write simple, idiomatic and easy to understand code!**

Comment: I think this is the best solution in production, but I accepted the other answer because it answers to the problem.