# std::basic_string as a parameter of a function template cannot be deduced from const char*

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion, template-argument-deduction

Why does putting `std::basic_string` as a parameter of a function template will fail to deduce from `const char*`, but it can be deduced successfully when it is constructed directly?

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
template<class Char/*, class Traits, class Allocator*/>   
                      //^doesn't matter whether the second and third template parameter is specified
void printString(std::basic_string<Char/*, Traits, Allocator*/> s)
{
    std::cout << s;
}
int main()
{
    printString("hello");    //nope
    std::basic_string s{ "hello" };//works
}
```

I found a relevant post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780030/template-deduction-guide-for-function), but the answers didn't explain the reason behind

Comment: The compiler wouldn't be able to pick a type if multiple specializations have matching constructors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because implicit conversion (from `const char*` to `std::basic_string<char>`) is not considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions), which fails in deducing the template parameter `Char`.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

You can specify the template argument explicitly,

```
printString<char>("hello");
```

Or pass an `std::basic_string` explicitly.

```
printString(std::basic_string("hello"));
```

Comment: What counts as an "implicit conversion"? If it is a constructor which can be called with only one argument, I still get error for example putting ``std::pair<T1, T2>`` as a parameter, and called with ``printPair({1,2})``. But it takes 2 arguments to construct.

Comment: @szppeter It refers to the conversion from `const char*` to `std::basic_string<char>`. Sorry I can't get what you meant about `std::pair`. Could you provide code snippet for it?

Comment: Eg. ``template<typename T1, typename T2> void printPair(std::pair<T1, T2>p) { std::cout<<p.first<<p.second;}  int main(){ printPair({1,2}); }``

Comment: @szppeter Same issue here. The braced-init-list `{1,2}` could convert to (construct) `std::pair`, but it's not considered in template deduction. If you specify the template arguments like `printPair<int, int>({1,2});` to bypass the deduction, then `{1,2}` is converted to `std::pair` and then passed to `printPair`, everything is fine.

Comment: So is it basically that any class templates cannot be deduced and constructed without specifying its type if it is a argument in a function template (in the form of my question)?

Comment: @szppeter, They can be deduced, just not when you pass in a different type. Your pair still has the same fundamental problem: What would the compiler deduce `T1` and `T2` to be if multiple specializations had matching constructors? (e.g., It's perfectly possible for there to be later specializations like `pair<Foo, Foo>` and `pair<Bar, Bar>` that both have a constructor taking `std::initializer_list<int>`.) It's impossible in general, and C++ isn't known for specifying how something works some of the time and then erroring when the code falls outside of those specific cases.

Comment: @szppeter If it requires implicit conversion to get the type which matches function parameter exactly, yes.